# Express post request body returns undefined and stores null values to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I need help on my MERN stack app, I'm using the mongodb native driver (no mongoose) and my express server functions well and return results with postman but I'm having some problems with my post request in the front-end. Using axios I'm able to run the get request and display the data in the browser but with post request; it returns undefined and inserts null values into the database. I'm not sure if it's a body-parser issue but I'm already using the express.json and express.urlencoded middlewares and it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code.

**Database Setup:**

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;
require('dotenv').config();
const url = process.env.MONGO_URI;
const db_name = process.env.DB_NAME;

const client = new MongoClient(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const state = {
  db: null,
};

const startConnection = (cb) => {
  /* If there's a database connection */
  if (state.db) {
    /* Execute the callback function */
    cb();
  } else {
    client.connect((err) => {
      if (err) {
        cb(err);
      } else {
        /* initialize the database */
        state.db = client.db(db_name);
        cb();
      }
    });
  }
};

const getDB = () => {
  return state.db;
};

const getPrimaryKey = (_id) => {
  return ObjectID(_id);
};

module.exports = { getDB, startConnection, getPrimaryKey };
```

**EXPRESS: Server**

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
require('dotenv').config();
const port = process.env.port || 8080;
const db = require('./db');
const db_col = String(process.env.DB_COLLECTION);

db.startConnection((err) => {
  if (err) {
    con_notification = `Unable to connect to the database ${err}`;
    console.log(con_notification);
  } else {
    con_notification = 'Connected to the database';
    console.log(con_notification);
  }
});

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
let con_notification;

/* Middlewares */
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
/* Logger */
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use('/list', router);

/* Get data from the database */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.getDB()
    .collection(db_col)
    .find({})
    .toArray((err, docs) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
      }
    });
});

/* Find one */
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const parameterID = req.params.id;
  db.getDB()
    .collection(db_col)
    .findOne({ _id: db.getPrimaryKey(parameterID) }, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(doc);
        res.json(doc);
      }
    });
});

/* Update one */
router.patch('/edit/title/:id', (req, res) => {
  const parameterID = req.params.id;
  const listname = req.body.list_name.trim();
  db.getDB()
    .collection(db_col)
    .updateOne(
      { _id: db.getPrimaryKey(parameterID) },
      { $set: { list_name: listname } },
      (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(doc);
          res.json(doc);
        }
      }
    );
});

/* Update child list item */
router.put('/edit/items/:id', (req, res) => {
  const parameterID = req.params.id;
  const listitems = req.body.list_items;
  db.getDB()
    .collection(db_col)
    .updateOne(
      { _id: db.getPrimaryKey(parameterID) },
      { $set: { list_items: listitems } },
      (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(doc);
          res.json(doc);
        }
      }
    );
});

/* Post */
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  const new_list = req.body;
  db.getDB()
    .collection(db_col)
    .insertOne(
      {
        list_name: new_list.list_name,
        list_items: new_list.list_items,
      },
      (err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(docs);
          res.json(docs);
        }
      }
    );
});

/* Delete one */
router.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  const parameterID = req.params.id;
  db.getDB()
    .collection(db_col)
    .deleteOne({ _id: db.getPrimaryKey(parameterID) }, (err, docs) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
      }
    });
});

app.listen(port, console.log(`Server listening to ${port}`));
```

**REACT: Reducer**

```
import { FETCHING, SUCCESS, ERROR } from '../actions/actionTypes';

export const initialState = {
  status: '',
  data: [],
};

const appReducer = (state, { type, response } = {}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case FETCHING:
      return { ...initialState, status: FETCHING };
    case SUCCESS:
      return { ...initialState, status: SUCCESS, data: response };
    case ERROR:
      return { ...initialState, status: ERROR, data: response };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default appReducer;
```

**Action types:**

```
export const FETCHING = 'FETCHING';
export const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';
export const ERROR = 'ERROR';

/* Action Creators */
export const fetching = () => ({ type: FETCHING });
export const success = (response) => ({ type: SUCCESS, response });
export const error = (response) => ({ type: ERROR, response });
```

**Custom Hook that is loaded into context provider:**

```
import { useCallback, useReducer } from 'react';
import appReducer, { initialState } from '../reducers/reducer';
import { fetching, success, error } from '../actions/actionTypes';
import axios from 'axios';

const useApiRequest = (params) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, initialState);

  const getRequest = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch(fetching());
    try {
      const response = await axios({ method: 'get', url: '/list' });
      dispatch(success(response.data));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(error(e));
    }
  }, []);

  const postRequest = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch(fetching());
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/list/add',
        params,
      });
      dispatch(success(response.data));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(error(e));
    }
  }, [params]);

  const patchUpdateRequest = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch(fetching());
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'patch',
        url: '/edit/title/:id',
        params,
      });
      dispatch(success(response.data));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(error(e));
    }
  }, [params]);

  const putUpdateRequest = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch(fetching());
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'put',
        url: '/edit/items/:id',
        params,
      });
      dispatch(success(response.data));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(error(e));
    }
  }, [params]);

  const deleteRequest = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch(fetching());
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'delete',
        url: '/delete/:id',
        params,
      });
      dispatch(success(response.data));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(error(e));
    }
  }, [params]);

  return [
    state,
    getRequest,
    postRequest,
    patchUpdateRequest,
    putUpdateRequest,
    deleteRequest,
  ];
};

export default useApiRequest;
```

**Context Provider:**

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import useApiRequest from '../custom-hooks/useApiRequest';

const AppContext = createContext();

export const AppcontextProvider = (props) => {
  const [
    state,
    getRequest,
    postRequest,
    patchUpdateRequest,
    putUpdateRequest,
    deleteRequest,
  ] = useApiRequest({});

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        state,
        getRequest,
        postRequest,
        patchUpdateRequest,
        putUpdateRequest,
        deleteRequest,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppContext;
```

**App enclosed with the context provider:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/header/Header';
import Main from './components/main/Main';
import { AppcontextProvider } from './context/AppContext';
import './stylesheets/index.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <AppcontextProvider>
      <div className='App'>
        <Header />
        <Main />
      </div>
    </AppcontextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Navigation Sidebar**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AddList from '../modals/AddList';
import DeleteList from '../modals/DeleteList';

import Modal from 'react-modal';

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

function Navigation() {
  const [addModalStatus, setAddModalStatus] = useState(false);
  const [deleteModalStatus, setDeleteModalStatus] = useState(false);

  const handleAddModal = () => {
    setAddModalStatus((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const handleDeleteModal = () => {
    setDeleteModalStatus((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <aside className='navigation'>
      <nav>
        <button className='btn-rec' onClick={handleAddModal}>
          Add New List
        </button>
        <button className='btn-rec' onClick={handleDeleteModal}>
          Delete List
        </button>
      </nav>
      <Modal isOpen={addModalStatus} onRequestClose={handleAddModal}>
        <header className='modal-header'>Create New List</header>
        <div className='modal-body'>
          <AddList exitHandler={handleAddModal} />
        </div>
        <footer className='modal-footer'>
          <button onClick={handleAddModal} className='btn-circle'>
            x
          </button>
        </footer>
      </Modal>
      <Modal isOpen={deleteModalStatus} onRequestClose={handleDeleteModal}>
        <header className='modal-header'>Delete List</header>
        <div className='modal-body'>
          <DeleteList exitHandler={handleDeleteModal} />
        </div>
        <footer className='modal-footer'>
          <button onClick={handleDeleteModal} className='btn-circle'>
            x
          </button>
        </footer>
      </Modal>
    </aside>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

**Main**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Listarea from './Listarea';

function Main() {
  return (
    <main className='App-body'>
      <Navigation />
      <Listarea />
    </main>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

**Modal for posting new list:**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import AppContext from '../../context/AppContext';

const AddList = ({ exitHandler }) => {
  const { postRequest } = useContext(AppContext);
  const [newList, setNewList] = useState({});
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  /* On load set focus on the input */
  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

  const handleAddList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const new_list = {
      list_name: inputRef.current.value,
      list_items: [],
    };
    setNewList(new_list);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    postRequest(newList);
    exitHandler();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='generic-form'>
      <input
        type='text'
        ref={inputRef}
        placeholder='List Name'
        onChange={handleAddList}
      />
      <input type='submit' value='ADD' className='btn-rec' />
    </form>
  );
};

export default AddList;
```

**Listarea GET REQUEST:**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AppContext from '../../context/AppContext';
import ParentListItem from './list-templates/ParentListItem';
import { FETCHING, SUCCESS, ERROR } from '../../actions/actionTypes';

function Listarea() {
  const {
    state,
    getRequest
  } = useContext(AppContext);

  const { status, data } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(status);
  }, [status]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRequest('/list');
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='list-area'>
      {status === FETCHING && (
        <p className='empty-notif'>Loading data from the database</p>
      )}
      {status === ERROR && (
        <p className='empty-notif'>Something went wrong: {ERROR}</p>
      )}
      {status === SUCCESS && (
        <ul className='parent-list'>
          {data.map((list) => (
            <ParentListItem key={list._id} {...list} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Listarea;
```

**GET REQUEST Result:**

[image]

**POST REQUEST Error**

[image]

**Server log: Shows undefined values for list_name and list_items**

[image]

**Mongodb cloud atlas: Collection record shows null values:**

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Please, can you post the code snippets in the snapshots as text(formatted as code blocks) instead of images - that would make it easier to work with.

Comment: Hi @Tunmee I have updated the questions with text format, the post request action happens in the modal code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:**

In the AddList component, you have this `handleSubmit` function that calls the `postRequest` function to create a new list in the server. You are passing in a `newList` variable as an argument to the function:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    postRequest(newList);
    exitHandler();
  };
```

However, the `postRequest` function itself does not accept any argument as seen in the declaration:

```
  const postRequest = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch(fetching());
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/list/add',
        params,
      });
      dispatch(success(response.data));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(error(e));
    }
  }, [params]);
```

Because of this, details of the new list to be created never gets to the server, consequently, null values are inserted into the DB.

**The fix**
The fix for this would be to make the `postRequest` function accept a data argument to be passed along to the Axios configuration, something like this:

```
const postRequest = useCallback(async (data) => {
    dispatch(fetching());
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/list/add',
        params,
        // Pass data argument to axios here
        data,
      });
      dispatch(success(response.data));
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(error(e));
    }
  }, [params]);
```

More details about what the data config means [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).
Now, whenever you call the `postRequest` method with some data as an argument as you are doing in the `handleSubmit` function, the data gets sent to the server and then a new list should be created.

Also, I noticed this problem is not just specific to `postRequest` alone, some other request helpers(e.g `patchUpdateRequest`, `putUpdateReqeust` e.t.c) in the `useApiReqeust` custom hook are not properly written. I suggest you check out the documentation on Axios configuration [here](https://github.com/axios/axios), then improve the request helpers to make them more configurable with function parameters.

Comment: thank you so much, it works now I am able to save the right data in the database but the page refreshes every time i submit and i get a TypeError: data.map is not a function and when I refresh it again the page loads with the inserted data. I tried calling the getRequest function inside the "try" of each request just below the dispatch(success(response.data)) but to no avail.

Comment: I kinda see why you are having the TypeError, however, it's another long answer. Perhaps, you can post the issue as a new question and I would follow up on that.